# Wordpress behind reverse proxy admin issues

Tags: wordpress, reverse-proxy

basically as title says i got a wp behind reverse proxy.
Let's say, the domain is `***`, and wordpress is `*******/blog`
Here are the wp-config.php edits that allow it to work this way:

```
define('.ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH.', '/blog');
define('.COOKIE_DOMAIN.', 'www.***.com');
define('.COOKIEPATH.', '/blog');
define('.SITECOOKIEPATH.', '.');


if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $list = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $list[0];
  }
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'https://www.***.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME','https://www.***.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.***.com/blog');
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'https://www.***.com/blog';
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.***.com/blog';
$_SERVER[ 'SERVER_ADDR' ] = 'www.***.com/blog';


define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("https://www.***.com/wp-admin",
                                      "https://www.***.com/blog/wp-admin",
                                      $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Now, it all works perfectly, but when I m in some places in admin panel, lets say comments, if i submit forms, WP goes to *******/wp-admin instead of *******/blog/wp-admin and crashes to 404.

**UPDATE**

tried the VHost approach, added this to my httpd.conf

```
Listen 80 <VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wp-admin 
  ServerName https://***/blog/wp-admin 

# Other directives here 
</VirtualHost>
```

but strangely got a redirect loop whenever i go to /blog after this

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where does your wordpress site is installed? i mean in which folder of your virtual host?

Comment: `var/www` (not `www/wordpress`, just in `var/www`), why?

Comment: would it be more simple to create a vhost for your site? Because you're rewriting the "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" but it changes the native workflow of wordpress.

Comment: that line was an experiment, i dont have it now and it still works same way...what do u mean create a vhost?

Comment: check this link : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html . I mean create a virtual host for https://www.***.com/blog/wp-admin/ for document root www/sitefolder/wp-admin . you see?

Comment: interesting idea! tried to do like in their manual -
`Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wp-admin
    ServerName https://***/blog/wp-admin
  
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>`
but strangely got a redirect loop whenever i go to /blog after this

Comment: Now we have 2018. Do you have a solution? I have a reverse proxy using a pathprefix - not a subdomain - and everything works fine - except the wp-admin. It seems to ignore the set wp_home and wp_siteurl...

Answer (score 6):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] do not contains the full URL, so you should replace only /wp-admin/. Given your example:

```
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",
                                            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: 6 years later and it's still relevant. this helped me fix my issue with my blog on Kinsta. thanks @sdocio!

Comment: man, this is 2021 April and you saved me 2 weeks debuging WP for this sh**t

Comment: will add keywords here to save others in future: WordPress, AWS, Cloudfront, /blog, subfolder, subdirectory

Comment: Root cause seems to be wordpress not always respecting it's settings. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53998

Comment: This only solved half of my problem, I seem to have issues with the editor not saving....